# Django encrypt FileField before saving it

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to save pdfs in the disk with django which is easy. However I want to encrypt them before saving them. As far as i know i should rewrite the save of the model to encrypt the file content before making the super().save()

The problem is that i'm not managing to encryopt the content, i've tried with:

```
self.file.write(f.encrypt(self.file.read()))
```

However it does not modify anything. I'm usinf fernet for encryptation however that is not the problem because if read the content is readed properly and if i encrypted it it works but the write is not storing anything.
In fact once i call the super function it stored in plain.
I'm not seeing with the debbuger where the content of the file is to modify it or how should i do it.

Thanks!

Comment: i think you have to use `InMemoryUploadedFile` like e.g : `file = InMemoryUploadedFile(encypted_file, 'FileField', name, content_type, size, None)`

Comment: Well i've discovered that if i write the self.file.read() the file i write is corrupted so i don't know how to read the whole file.

Comment: Seems that i solved, information was laking because i had to do seek(0) as django used the stream and was not at 0. With this and replacing file.file.file for a custom  ByteIO() where i wrote the encrytped works